# AWS amplify not recognizing vite react NX monorepo

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vite, monorepo, nx-monorepo

I have a new NX monorepo with 3 apps. Two of them are bundled with Vite and one is a NextJS project.

When I deploy the vite app to AWS Amplify it recognizes the app folder as NextJS-SSR! It also throws the error

```bash
CustomerError: Can't find required-server-files.json in build output directory
```

**Vite | amplify.yml**

```yaml
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npx nx build vite-app
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: dist/apps/vite-app
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - node_modules/**/*
      buildPath: /
    appRoot: apps/vite-app
```

#### Note

If I remove the NextJS app using `nx remove nextjs-app` and deploy to AWS Amplify with just the vite apps. The app deploys correctly.

I don't understand why Amplify is recognizing the app as NextJS and how to get rid off it. I need to deploy two applications with vite and two with nextjs.

**P.S**: I can provide more info if needed!

## Edit

**NextJS | amplify.yml**

```yaml
version: 1
applications:
  - frontend:
      phases:
        preBuild:
          commands:
            - node -v
            - npm ci
        build:
          commands:
            - npx nx build nextjs-app
      artifacts:
        baseDirectory: dist/apps/nextjs-app
        files:
          - '**/*'
      cache:
        paths:
          - .next/cache/**/*
          - node_modules/**/*
      buildPath: /
    appRoot: apps/nextjs-app
```

The Nextjs project is deployed successfully without any issues.

Comment: can you please post the complete amplify.yml file (with both Vite and Next apps)?

Comment: shouldn't the `artifacts.baseDirectory` be `dist/apps/nextjs-app/.next` as this is where the required-server-files.json resides?

Comment: The nextjs deployment is working fine with this amplify.yml. The issue is actually with the vite deployment. In fact the `/.next` was originally added to the amplify.yml but it did not work. The nx build nextjs-app does not create the `.next` file in the `dist/nextjs-app` folder. After removing the `/.next` part, the nextjs deployment worked.